# RxJava Kotlin how to get separated objects from single observable<String>

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, flatmap

RxJava Kotlin flatmap don't return separated objects from splitted string. instead it returns List

```
val source: Observable<String> = Observable.just("521934/2342/FOXTROT")
.flatMap{Observable.fromArray(it.split("/"))}
.subscribe{Log.d(TAG, "$it")}
```

It returns list:

```
[521934, 2342, FOXTROT]
```

But book (*Thomas Nield : Learning RxJava / 2017 / Page 114*) says it has to return separated strings

```
521934
2342
FOXTROT
```

[example from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUNu9.png)

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html says that it returns Single object. In my case I got Single List object. So, documentation says true. But I want to get result as in book example!

How I can split the list and get separated objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `flatMapIterable`, so you can get a stream of the items from the list:

```
Observable.just("521934/2342/FOXTROT")
            .flatMap { input -> Observable.fromArray(input.split("/")) }
            .flatMapIterable { items -> items }
            .subscribe { item -> Log.d(TAG, item) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `fromIterable`:

```
Observable.just("521934/2342/FOXTROT")
                .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it.split("/")) }
                .subscribe{
                    Log.d(TAG, "$it")
                }
```

In case of array you would have to use a spread operator additionaly since `fromArray` takes a vararg argument list:

```
Observable.fromArray(*arrayOf("521934","2342","FOXTROT"))
```